# Check whether certificate is accepted on device

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate

How can i check whether a certificate which I included in my android app is being accepted on my nodejs server. Is there any way? Something like a network monitor (if yes, how can i check this?)

I added my certificate like mentioned here: http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

And added it to my Retrofit client and as far I can see, it is working with the custom HttpClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, just use a wrong certificate ...

Comment: Isn't this answer providing an answer to a different question? The different question would be *"How can I check an incorrect certificate used in my android app is being rejected by nodejs server"*.

Comment: I just wanted to know if one certificate is working. My Service was working with that one certificate, then i switched the certificate to another and the Service was not working, so I assume that the first one is working.

Comment: *"I just wanted to know if one certificate is working."* - in this case, you would use the correct client certificate and verify that its accepted by the server. They are two different use cases.